Getting this error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis' after upgrading Gradle to 7.3.3
For some reason I need to compile my android project with compileSdkVersion 33 and targetSdkVersion 33, so I upgraded my Gradle version to 7.3.3 meanwhile I switched AGP to 7.2.2, also I set my JDK as java-11, and I confirmed that I have installed android sdk 33 properly,I thought everything should be ok, but once I synch my project , it keeps giving me this: Could not resolve all files for configuration :app:androidApis .
I googled this and almost all answers are telling me that it was due to AGP version does not match Gradle version. but in my case, I should've got everything right, and some other answers say that I should downgrade the compileSdkVersion , that's not what I expected,so ,please save me! It's killing me...
Here are my configs:
  android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"

        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 8
        versionName "v1.0.6-20240611"
        multiDexEnabled true
        flavorDimensions "versionCode"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    ...
  }

gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://mirrors.aliyun.com/macports/distfiles/gradle/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip

Project Structure
Gradle version
AS version
android sdk
So did get something wrong? Thanks !
I tried most of the suggestions on website I googled, but still keep getting this error. I hope my project can be synched properly.

Use:
Android Gradle Plugin Version 7.1.3
Gradle Version 6.7.1
Gradle version is matched with the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version and It compatible with Android SDK-33 and 34
